# Using numbers in lists as characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a calculator with the following code:

```
number_1 = " "
while number_1 not in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
    number_1 = raw_input("Please enter your first number:")
    if number_1 not in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
        print "ERROR: Please type a valid number:"


print number_1
operator_symbol = " "
while operator_symbol not in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
    operator_symbol = raw_input("Please enter an appropriate operator symbol:")
    if operator_symbol not in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
        print "ERROR: Please type one of the following operator symbols: +, -, *, /."
print operator_symbol


number_2 = " "
while number_2 not in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
    number_2 = raw_input("Please enter your second number:")
    if number_2 not in ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]:
            print "ERROR: Please type a valid number"
print number_2
```

They are spaced out while I work on them. For `number_1` and `number_2` I have defined the characters that I want to be used (`'0'`-`'9'`), yet when I use a number larger than `9`, it gives an error.

I want to use `'0'`-`'9'` as characters available, not the specific numbers.

Comment: Why don't you `try: int(number_1)` to see if they're valid as integers? Alternatively, you need to check that `all` characters are digits, or use `str.isdigit`

Comment: Hi, where would I put     int(number_1) and     str.isdigit ? Thanks

Comment: Why not try it out and see? Have a look at e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/3001761

Comment: This is very confusing to me, is there no simple way to apply them as characters instead of specific numbers?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by *"as characters instead of specific numbers"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the .isdigit() method of strings you can check whether the input supplied is a number or not.

On how to use it, you can do the following:

```
number_1= raw_input("Enter your first number")
while not number_1.isdigit():
    number_1 = raw_input("Error: Please enter a valid number: ")
```

Similarly for number_2.. The trick is asking for the number as a input first and if the number is not a number then continue asking the user for the number

That should do.

Comment: Hi mate, this is helpful but it doesn't seem to work. If I type a character other than a digit, it re-prints the original question instead of a reply to the error. :S

Comment: It's working in my machine.. Do you need to stop asking for input? Then the code will be different..

Comment: This is a image to see it in action: [http://postimg.org/image/eegtihz8p/](http://postimg.org/image/eegtihz8p/)

Comment: I have everything sorted, BUT, for either number_1 or number_2, if the user types anything other than a digit, it re-prints the "Please enter your first number" instead of printing "ERROR: Please enter a valid number". Sorry i'm just confused as to why it's ignoring it.

Comment: I understood what you want.. I'm editing my answer for you. Kindly wait

Comment: Modified.. I hope it helps.

Comment: Everything is working... finally lol. Thanks for your help!:)

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if `number_1` is a single digit (one of the elements in your list).

What you want to do instead is check that `number_1` is a string only containing digits.
You can do this using the [.isdigit()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) method.

Also, instead of double checks (both in the while and in the if), you should only do the check once:

```
number_1 = raw_input("Please enter your first number:")
while not number_1.isdigit()
    number_1 = raw_input("ERROR: Please type a valid number:")
```

Comment: Thanks, what else do I need to change and how do I account for the situation where someone will type a character other than a digit? Thanks again.

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe this makes it easier to understand.